# How to insert values from multiple forms into same row in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Basically, I have multiple forms where the data will be saved into a SQL Servre database. A `datatable` will then display the compiled data. However, because I've saved the data into the same `database` from two different forms, the datatable will have two rows (see [screenshot]). And because of my situation, I have to allow nulls to my data.

Hence, how can I save multiple values from different `forms` into the same row in SQL Server database? Hope it is possible. Below is my code:

**Form 1**

```
private void Bnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do SQL for Inspecdate
  string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Delivery_Inspection.Properties.Settings.SavertbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
  sqlconn.Open();
  string Dateinspect = DateTime.Parse(DTinspec.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Rtbdata(Inspectiondate) values ('" + Dateinspect + "' )", sqlconn);
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (i != 0)
       {
        MessageBox.Show("Saved");
       }
    else
       {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
       }

    sqlconn.Close();
    this.Hide();
    FormsCollection.autodataset.Show();
    }
```

**Form 2 - Same as above except the code below**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Rtbdata(Vehnum) values ('" + TBvehicleno.Text + "')", sqlconn);

this.Hide();
FormsCollection.datatable.Show();
```

Comment: In general, either have a single insert, or an insert and then an update.

Comment: You really need to fix that injection issue first. Always parametrise your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have ensured that you can only have one instance of Form1 and one instance of Form2 open at the same time, then you simply need to combine the two insert statements into one, taking values from both forms simultaneously. The "other" form (i.e. Form2 if you are reacting to the click event of Form1 and vice versa) is accessible through the Forms collection. 
Also please research SQL injection. Your code is very vulnerable. Use parameters for your inserts. This will also enable you to add Dates as date types and not as strings. 
Finally please wrap your SqlConnections in using blocks. 
You will find plenty of examples on this site of all these points, with a little research.